# What causes my SAM template to generate that many errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I've been trying to get my SAM template working. I get the General idea of having a SAM template but i dont understand the logic behind the errors i keep getting from CloudFormation
Are my outputs correct? I only use the API's (not the functions?). I am able to do GET requests, but CORS is preventing me from doing the PUT and POST requests.
What is redundant and what am i missing?

**The error:** "Status reason
Unresolved resource dependencies [ServerlessRestApi] in the Outputs block of the template"

**I've been getting the following error alot too:** "The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: abad588e-02ee-4fc6-a668-43b30bec6aaf; Proxy: null)"

**Template.yaml:**

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  SAM Template

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10

Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: ApiGatewayApi
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE'"
        AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
  DeclineSituationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: DeclineSituation
      CodeUri: decline-situation/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        DeclineSituationAPI:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /decline-situation
            Method: put
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
  AcceptSituationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: AcceptSituation
      CodeUri: accept-situation/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        AcceptSituationAPI:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accept-situation
            Method: post
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
  GetIncidentsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: GetIncidents
      CodeUri: get-incidents/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        GetIncidentsAPI:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /incidents
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
  GetSituationsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: GetSituations
      CodeUri: get-situations/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Policies: AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole
      Events:
        GetSituationsAPI:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /situations
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
  GetRecoveriesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      FunctionName: GetRecoveries
      CodeUri: get-recoveries/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Policies: AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole
      Events:
        GetRecoveriesAPI:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /recoveries
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
  ReadNotificationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: ReadNotification
      CodeUri: read-notification/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: Situations
  Incidents:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: AIMAS-Incidents
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: incidentId
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: situationId
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: incidentId
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
  Situations:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: AIMAS-Situations
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: situationId
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: situationId
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
  Recoveries:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: AIMAS-Recoveries
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: recoveryId
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: situationId
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: incidentId
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: recoveryId
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  #Incidents
  GetIncidentsAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for GetIncidentsAPI"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/incidents/"
  GetIncidentsFunction:
    Description: "GetIncidents Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt GetIncidentsFunction.Arn
  #Recoveries
  GetRecoveriesAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for GetRecoveriesAPI"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/recoveries/"
  GetRecoveriesFunction:
    Description: "GetRecoveries Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt GetRecoveriesFunction.Arn
  #Situations
  AcceptSituationFunction:
    Description: "AcceptSituationFunction Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt AcceptSituationFunction.Arn
  AcceptSituationAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for GetSituationsAPI"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/accept-situation/"
  DeclineSituationFunction:
    Description: "DeclineSituationFunction Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt DeclineSituationFunction.Arn
  DeclineSituationAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for GetSituationsAPI"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/decline-situation/"
  GetSituationsAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for GetSituationsAPI"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/situations/"
  GetSituationsFunction:
    Description: "GetSituations Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt GetSituationsFunction.Arn
  #Read Notifications
  ReadNotificationFunction:
    Description: "ReadNotification Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt ReadNotificationFunction.Arn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your template.

```
    E3039 The set of Attributes in AttributeDefinitions: ['incidentId', 'situationId'] and KeySchemas: ['incidentId'] must match at Resources/Incidents/Properties

    E3039 The set of Attributes in AttributeDefinitions: ['incidentId', 'recoveryId', 'situationId'] and KeySchemas: ['recoveryId'] must match at Resources/Recoveries/Properties

    E1019 Parameter ServerlessRestApi for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/GetIncidentsAPI/Value/Fn::Sub
    x.yml:156:5

    E1019 Parameter ServerlessRestApi for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/GetRecoveriesAPI/Value/Fn::Sub
    x.yml:163:5

    E1019 Parameter ServerlessRestApi for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/AcceptSituationAPI/Value/Fn::Sub
    x.yml:173:5

    E1019 Parameter ServerlessRestApi for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/DeclineSituationAPI/Value/Fn::Sub
    x.yml:179:5

    E1019 Parameter ServerlessRestApi for Fn::Sub not found at Outputs/GetSituationsAPI/Value/Fn::Sub
    x.yml:182:5
```

Use [cfn-linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) and the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html) for generating the template, there are plenty of good examples in the documentation as well.

Comment: Recommend [an IDE extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) to automatically inline [`cfn-lint`](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/#editor-plugins) results as well

Comment: @PatMyron to be frank, I myself use vim, and people take things related to editors very seriously. So I don't want to offend anyone here.